# Is this infinite family of non-trivial snarks resulting from the first Celmins-Swart?

Tags: graph-theory

Non-trivial snark is cubic graph with chromatic index $4$, girth
at least $5$ and doesn't to contain three edges whose deletion results in a disconnected graph, each of whose components is nontrivial.

Let $S$ be the first [Celmins-Swart snark](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Celmins-SwartSnarks.html) and $G$ the graph with edges $[(8, 11), (9, 14)]$ deleted from $S$.  The edges of $G$ are:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 10), (2, 6), (2, 8), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 8), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 12), (6, 7), (7, 9), (9, 10), (10, 18), (11, 15), (11, 16), (12, 13), (12, 16), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 17), (15, 22), (16, 19), (17, 18), (17, 21), (18, 26), (19, 23), (19, 25), (20, 21), (20, 22), (20, 25), (21, 24), (22, 23), (23, 24), (24, 26), (25, 26)]
```

Chose integer $n>1$ and make $n$ copies of $G_i$ for $i \in [0,n-1]$.

Let $v_{i,j}$ denote vertex $j$ in the $G_i$.

Add the following edges $\{(v_{i,9},v_{i+1,8}),(v_{i,14},v_{i+1,11})\}$ 
for $i \in [0,n-1]$ where addition is modulo $n$.

This construction produces non-trivial snark for $n$ at least up to $26$.

> Is this infinite family of non-trivial snarks?

The sparse6 string for $n=2$ is:

```
:s_P?[QCC`?wkCPF_RP?qKKdBhg}SKccALO?R`cxXUgUdcwH]uYavbkG|[NVBl}uaoukyHL_RXDE\RcRWtQn[YUvTmT^mWUSiuoZW~
```

Comment: Oh, this appears easy. $\chi'(G)=4$, the girth doesn't increase and the only problem is connectivity...